# Removing Methods with Java ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I'm trying to use the [Java ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/index.html) library, and after quite a bit of research, I haven't found the solutions to a problem I'm having. I'm trying to make an application that does the following:

- Reads classes from an external Jar file
- Remove completely certain methods from specified classes
- Print to console or store the modified class' compiled bytecode or compiled class contents, like from `new String(cw.toByteArray())`, cw being an instance of `ClassWriter` (Similar to how you would see if you edited a class file with notepad)

I have been able to read bytecode and the compiled class contents, but not remove methods. I haven't been able to find any working code, only partial code with very little explanation of how to implement it.

Comment: `new String(cw.toByteArray())` doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: Instead of `new String(cw.toByteArray())` to view contents, why not use a Textifier? It makes reading the class way easier as it prints out the bytecode of a given class in a nicely formatted way.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a `ClassVisitor` that overrides the `visitMethod` method and return `null` from this method without invoking `super.visitMethod` when you discover a certain pattern.

This way, the method in question is skipped and not added to the created class file.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond but how can I use a class like that and keep the same class data from it? After I read the class' bytecode it reads the same.

Comment: You would need to write it back to disk.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? (sorry, I'm a bit of a noob at ASM) and are there any good tutorials on what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: From a class writer, you can get the byte array that is the class file. Write it back to its root location.